# Table array sorting

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a program that basically allows a viewer to enter an employees name, and their salary, and then hit a confirmation button. When this button is hit, a table row and cell is added for both the salary and employee name in a table below. Now, the results are also sorted by alphabetical order. However, the issue is that the results aren't sorted until after the display of the createbody function. So, the alphabetical order isn't updated until after a new employee is entered. My goal is to have the results sort in real-time, **OR have a separate button that will sort the results**. Either way is fine. Does anyone have a solution for either of these? code is listed below:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang="en"> 
<head> 
<meta charset="UTF-8" /> 
<title> Table Entry </title> 
</head> 
<body> 
<input type="text" id="fullName" value="" placeholder="Firstname"> :Enter employee name <br> 
<input type="text" id="salary" value="" placeholder="Salary"> :Enter employee salary <br> 
<input type="button" value="click me add to employee list" onclick="addToArray()"> <p>&nbsp;</p> 
<input type="button" value="click me to sort employees" onclick="sortEm()"> <p>&nbsp;</p> 
<div id="tablediv">
<table border="1" id="source" cellspacing="3" cellpadding="3"> 
 <thead> 
  <tr> <th>Employee Name</th> <th>Employee Salary</th> </tr> 
 </thead> 
 <tbody id="sourceBody"> 
  <tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>&nbsp;</td></tr> 
 </tbody> 
</table> </div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

function sortEm() {
var tbl = document.getElementById('source');
var row = tbl.insertRow(1);
var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
row.deleteCell(0);
document.getElementById("tbl").deleteRow(1);


}
var NameSalaries= []; 
function addToArray() { 
  var fn = document.getElementById('fullName').value; 
  var sly = document.getElementById('salary').value; 
  var both = [fn,sly]; 
  NameSalaries.push(both); 
  createBody(NameSalaries); 
  document.getElementById('fullName').focus(); 
  NameSalaries.sort();
  } 

function createBody(NS) { 
  var tarr = []; 
  for (var i=0; i<NS.length; i++) { 
    tarr.push('<tr><td>'+NS[i][0]+'</td><td>'+NS[i][1]+'</td></tr>');  
  } document.getElementById('sourceBody').innerHTML = tarr.join(''); 
} 



</script> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: can't you sort the name salaries before creating the body ? just call `NameSalaries.sort()` and then the create body with the array sorted.

Comment: Try to abstract your use case as much as possible when asking a question here. We don't need to know about “employees”, “salaries”, or see your entire html markup. We just need to know that you have to render an array a sorted array of elements; unneeded precisions just discourage people from reading.

Comment: You're right christophe, thanks for the tip!

Comment: also..thanks to joel, who solved this problem. Sometimes..when you're up late at night..you just need someone to point out something simple. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical way to manage such a use case is by building a [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) pattern in order to enforce [separation of concerns](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns). In your code, everything is tangled together: the buttons logic and the table rendering happen in the same place.

In a MVC pattern, the **M**odel holds your data, the **V**iew renders it, and the **C**ontroller manages your logic, passing data from the model to the view when needed. The MVC design pattern is an excellent example of separating the different aspects of software functionality for better software maintainability. When those aspects are managed and well isolated, you won't stumble on considerations such as: “when does my table get sorted”.

Look into [Backbone](http://backbonejs.org) for a very modular and lightweight MVC framework for javascript, or into [AngularJS](https://angularjs.org/) or [EmberJS](http://emberjs.com/) for more ambitious web applications.